# how to make a vertical line segment in plot?

Tags: r

I have a plot(x, y) and I want to add a vertical line at x = 2 ONLY from y = 1 to 4. I want to use the lines() function but I'm having trouble limiting the y-range.

What's an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you add some sample datat and an example of the error vs what you want to see?

Comment: Can you add what you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example of using `plot` and `lines`. To draw a line from `(2, 1)` to `(2, 4)`, you have to provide the x coordinates and y coordinates as `(2, 2)` and `(1, 4)`:

```
plot(1:5)
lines(c(2, 2), c(1, 4))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`ggplot2` offers a very simple solution, too!

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
# Create some dummy data
data.frame(X = rpois(n = 10, lambda = 3), 
           Y = rpois(n = 10, lambda = 2)) %>% 
# Pipe to ggplot
    ggplot(aes(X, Y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_segment(aes(x = 1, xend = 1, y = 1, yend = 4), color = "red")
```

Within the aesthetics call to `geom_segment()` you can select the start and end points for your x and y parameters. You can then easily add multiple segments by simply adding `+ geom_segment(aes(...))` to the end of the code above.

[image]

Comment: for multiple segment, do I need to add + geom_segment(aes(...)) separately for each segment? Is there a way to do them in one line?

Comment: If you want multiple segments you could either add multiple `geom_segment` commands, or you could create a brand new table with a row number (for group), x, xend, y, and yend, then pass that to `geom_segment`!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, there is also a base graphics function in R that will do this:  segments(x0,y0,x1,y1):

```
plot(1:5)
segments(2,1,2,4)
```